# How parse radius CDR in logstash using grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

Is there any way to get fields from following message event using grok pattern
fields i have to parse in following and store in elastic as below

timestamp => NET-Log-Time

device_ip => NAS-IP-Address

message => message

```
Message => 
" Tue Nov 22 15:20:33 2011
    NET-Log-Time = "Tue Nov 22 15:20:31 2011\n"
    Acct-Status-Type = Start
    NET-Session-Ingress-CallId = 0
    NET-Session-Egress-CallId = 65535
    NET-Session-Generic-Id = 14
    Acct-Multi-Session-Id = "132200403114"
    NET-Ingress-Signaling-Group = 19992
    NET-Egress-Signaling-Group = 0
    NET-Ingress-Channel-Number = 23
    NET-Egress-Channel-Number = 0
    NET-Call-Origin = 1
    NET-Calling-Number = "1029"
    NET-Called-Number = "2006"
    NET-Calling-Name = "System Test"
    NET-Ingress-Channel-Id = "1:1:23"
    NET-Setup-Time = "1322004031"
    Acct-Session-Id = "0"
    NET-Firmware-Version = "2.0.0v107"
    NET-Local-Time-Zone = "PST8PDT"
    NET-Gw-Id = "f5a4fdc8f970ae35addf36"
    NET-Time-And-Day = "1322004031"
    NAS-Port = 1813
    Acct-Delay-Time = 0
    NAS-IP-Address = 134.56.227.230
    Acct-Unique-Session-Id = "df05da217dbe16e4"
    Timestamp = 1322004033
    Request-Authenticator = Verified"
```

Using %{GREEDYDATA:messageBody} i could extract

```
{
  "messageBody": "Mon Jun 14 18:08:54 2021"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing with radius too. I have to merge all these lines first,
you can do it with `multiline` either on the input codec / logstash filter(terminated). [multiline-codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.13/plugins-codecs-multiline.html)

This one is perfect example for you

```
    input {
      stdin {
        codec => multiline {
          pattern => "^\s"
          what => "previous"
        }
      }
    }
```

**pattern => "^\s"**
This match the beginning space of every line

**what => "previous"**
This is the action, what will you do if the line match the pattern. In this example will be appended to the previous line.

With your log sample I think the pattern would be `^\s{2,}` since you only want to merge those who have beginning 2 or more space.

Those appended to the other message have separator `\n`

Comment: Thanks!! But how do I get specific value from this message containing lot of \n and \t , for ex I need timestamp from NET-Log-Time
device_ip from NAS-IP-Address

Comment: These whole lines will be pressed into a single line. Then you can you whatever you desire. You can parse it with grok, but I will suggest you to do it with KV plugin. If my answer helps, you might want to accept it as answer or upvote it.